# What happens if you knockback Warwick while he ults?

Tags: league-of-legends

If you knockback an ulting Warwick, does it cancel the ult or does he just stand where he lands clawing the air?

Comment: If memory serves properly he just stands where he lands clawing the air. It's been too long for me to be sure enough to post this as an answer however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that interrupts the channel of a suppression ult will end the ultimate prematurely. This applies to Warwick, Malzahar, and Urgot, and any method that breaks a channel will likewise interrupt the ultimate, primarily: knockback/up, silence, and stun.

Originally, when warwick's ult was broken prematurely, he *did* continue clawing the air, but that behavior was patched out some time ago.